# IdnToAscii linker error

Tags: visual-c++, linker, msdn, idn

I am trying to use IdnToAscii in my code.
Accourding to msdn

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318149(v=vs.85).aspx

all I need is kernel32.dll. But I receive linking error when trying to build:

Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__IdnToAscii@20 referenced in function _wmain.

Including normaliz.lib to project solves the issue.

The question is why do I have to include it. Is it a mismatch in msdn documentation or I am missing something.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the 'Requirements' paragraph of the MSDN: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318149%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

There you can see that the IdnToAscii method is in the Normaliz.dll (not kernel32.dll)and to use this method you have to includes Normaliz.lib.

Comment: I assume msdn guys added this dependency recently. As you can see I commented under the post you mentioned. So at the Time I was writing that comment the kernel32 was mentioned as requirement.
Anyway Thanks for your response.